# Do I need to replace a shower tile that has been scratched?

Tags: bathroom, tile, waterproofing, marble

I am regrouting my bathroom and the shower floor tile has a scrape mark / maybe not cracked through....my question is can i continue ( i can live with the mark) or is it now not waterproof ? Do I need to replace the tile ( a bigger job that may interrupt the waterproof membrane ) what to do ? Thank you [image]

Answer (score 3):

Grout lines are never waterproof and a tiled surface should not be considered waterproof unless it has a rubber membrane underneath it as is the case with shower floor pans. If you can live with the scratch you will be just fine.